# How to Run a Runnable Jar without Java_Home

Tags: jar, runnable, java-home

I have a shared host server, I have no root privileges on it, I can't write in system files, so I can't configure Java_Home.
I am searching for a solution to deploy my java application on the server.
I have a runnable jar.
can't I transform it to a machine language that doesn't require java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no simple way to compile an entire an entire Java executable JAR into native binaries. If the machine does not have a JVM, this is quite a difficult problem.

If the machine is windows based, you might have success with [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), a free executable wrapping tool.

If not, I would recommend trying [packr](https://github.com/libgdx/packr), a similar tool supporting packaging for any system.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful. this might work with simple Java applications.
but for now I am using packr, and the generated executable shows errors related to spring boot.
I have tried to generate different types of fat jars to pass it to packr. (via spring package, maven assembly , maven package...)
it's like it can't find spring classes...